# Report generation using MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, report, tabular

The table name is ORDERS.

The table structure and data looks this:

Catno     | Bookno
'============='
1              |    4
1              |    6
1              |    7
2              |    3
2              |    9
3              |    1
3              |    5
3              |    7

Now, I need a report that looks like:

Cat No: 1    2    3 
'============='
                4   3   1
                6   9   5
             7        7

How to generate this report using mysql and PHP?

Comment: It looks like you are treating that as a junction table.

Comment: In raw mysql commands, add \G to transpose rows and columns

Comment: Please don't format questions with `&nbsp;` here - it makes subsequent editing difficult. Just use the code formatting tools - select your text and hit the code button.

Comment: (You've been downvoted probably because there is no indication of what software you will use to generate the report, and no indication of prior research. Questions should be a bit more specific here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Bookno SEPARATOR ' ') as booknum  FROM ORDERS BY Catno;
```

Result will be

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $catno=$row['Catno']
     $arrayResult[$catno]=explode(" ", $row['booknum']);
}
```

that `$arrarResult` gives data like you want